# Server Board S2600WT2R unable to set clock speed to 2400 MHz

Tags: memory, intel, bios

I have an [Intel® Server Board S2600WT2R](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/server-products/server-boards/dual-socket-server-boards/intel-server-board-s2600wt-family/intel-server-board-s2600wt2r.html)

I have set the Memory Operating Speed in the bios to 2400, but dmidecode reports that "Configured Clock Speed: 2134 MHz".  If I set the clock speed in the bios below 2133, the clock speed changes appropriately.  I have been through the [BIOS manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/server/sb/intelserversystembiossetuputilityguide10_final.pdf) and I believe I've set everything up properly.

I know what my RAM ([Kingston KVR24R17D4/16](http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/KVR24R17D4_16.pdf)) is not on the [Approved Memory List](http://www.cmtlabs.com/2012/memCertPartSearchResultsAll.asp?bNav=True&sManuf=Intel&outside=False&sMN=S2600wt&oSubmit=Search).

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual you linked states outright that:

> The supported memory speeds are 1333 MT/s, 1600 MT/s, 1866 MT/s, and 2133 MT/s. The actual memory speed capability depends on the memory configuration.

Comment: Wooops.  Although my Bios had the option to set the speed to 2400 MT/s, I see that the E5-2600 v3 processors themselves do not support 2400 MT/s.   Looks like I need a v4.